# Magento String problem

Tags: php, magento

I have the following piece of code and I'm looking to replace the **Price From:** bit with an image, the catch is it needs to pull in a dynamic path using `<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/assets/up-arrow.png') ?>`

```
$extraHtml .= $this->__('<div class="price-from">Price From:</div>');
```

How do I implement the image code in to my string?

Comment: Why you want translate part `<div class="price-from">` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks all very mangled. I assume the whole thing also runs through a translator, which would mean there is much wrong already 'cause no markup should go through translation.

Generally you could write:

```
$extraHtml .= $this->__('<div class="price-from">' . $this->getSkinUrl('images/assets/up-arrow.png') . '</div>');
```

Given, the getSkinUrl method returns the markup for the image. Otherwise you'd have to add an img tag. E.g. like in Anton S' answer.

```
$extraHtml .= $this->__('<div class="price-from"><img src="%s" /></div>', $this->getSkinUrl('images/assets/up-arrow.png'));
```

But the whole thing has strong code smells.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$extraHtml .= $this->__('<div class="price-from"><img src="'%s'" /></div>', $this->getSkinUrl('images/assets/up-arrow.png'));
```

although it makes no sense to put html in localization string